# Is there a way to detect which program the user is currently viewing in windows os?

Tags: c#, windows

This is just a side project of mine where I try to change the color of my mouse based on the program the user is currently viewing. For example the color would turn blue if it is Microsoft edge or Yellow if Google Chrome. Is there a way to figure out which program the user is currently viewing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GetForegroundWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633505(v=vs.85).aspx) in conjunction with [`Process.GetProcesses`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9(v=vs.110).aspx)

**GetForegroundWindow function**

> Retrieves a handle to the foreground window (the window with which the
>   user is currently working). The system assigns a slightly higher
>   priority to the thread that creates the foreground window than it does
>   to other threads.

**Process.GetProcesses Method ()**

> Creates a new Process component for each process resource on the local
>   computer.

**Example**

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

... 

// get the active window
var activatedHandle = GetForegroundWindow();

var processes = Process.GetProcesses();

// compare with the processes  
foreach (var proc in processes)
{

    if(activatedHandle == proc.MainWindowHandle)
    {
        // you now have the process name
        string processName = proc.ProcessName;

        return processName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not quite, use GetWindowThreadProcessId() to obtain the process id, Process.GetProcessById() from there.